# Argument Issue On Laravel Policy Method

Tags: laravel

My controller method:

```
public function store(StoreTradeRequest $request, StoreTradeService $service)
{
    $this->authorize('store', [Trade::class, $request->all()]);

    // ...
}
```

My policy:

```
public function store(User $user, array $request): Response|bool
{
    return $user->id == $request['trader_id'];
}
```

My code works but I have a problem with the second argument of the authorize method in the contoller. As you can see, it's an array of two items while I need only the request on the policy side. I don't understand why, but if I send only the request, I'm getting the following error:

```
Too few arguments, 1 passed, 2 expected.
```

I have nothing to do with "Trade::class," and it can't reach policy method, but somehow I need it there to make it work. Any idea what is wrong here?

**UPDATE**
I passed $request in every form I can imagine and the results are all the same.

```
'store', $request
'store', [$request]
'store', $request->all()
'store', $request->validated()
'store', [$request->all()]
'store', [$request->validated()]
```

Comment: Why you don't pass user from controller like auth()->user() for example?

Comment: you said if i remove `Trade::class`, you'll get Too few arguments. how you pass `$request->all()` when you remove `Trade::class`? update your question base on what you've tried.

Comment: @knubbe It's because user is added by Laravel automatically.

Comment: @Atlas-pio I did.

Comment: Can u try "StoreTradeRequest $request" instead of "array $request"

Comment: @Alper I tried your suggestion, and then removed the typehint from polict method, still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In General**

When you're trying to use policy by not using a model, you should use/register it in another way, because as i said, it meant to be used with a model, which in this case you're not using it and application want you to pass or inject it someway or another.

This is the regular way of registering policy which you should add your policy to `protected $policies`, which it is the way you said.

Laravel do the same way to discover your policy like as i explained.

**An answer to Comment and closing this**

`I think your answer has some good points and lots of unnecessary addition to the codebase which may helpful as an answer to a different question`

Below information are necessary to know, and I'll keep there here because there are good way and bad ways of doing things, but in other-hand you had issue with passing only request which you got the solution with better approach, and the reason for that is the purpose of class name and etc(Clean CODE & SOLID).

- First approach is a way of doing this using GATE, but this might use more lines, in other-hand it can be useful while doing routing(and blades and ...), because in most-cases you have arguments from route and etc.
- Second approach is more accurate but It's basically a trick to get a common thing to handle more scenarios and, because there's a specific purpose to the policy and range of what it can do to authorize.
- As i said It meant to be used with a model, but second approach might be used as a `api`, and of-course while you passing arguments, you will only pass required things, not other things to confuse people who try to read your code, which in this case, you're passing `Trade` but in policy, you've never used it.

Basic Example:

```
public function store(StoreTradeRequest $request, StoreTradeService $service)
{
    $this->authorize('store', [Trade::class, $request->all()]);
    // Change above line to below
    $this->authorize('store', $request->all());

    // ...
}
```

use `HandlesAuthorization` Trait like below :

```
use HandlesAuthorization;

// rest of the code look fine base on what you have in your mine.
public function store(User $user, array $request): bool
{
    return true;
}

// If user is guest, you can check for user too like below

// ?User $user
public function store(?User $user, array $request): bool
```

If by any chance you're trying to validate your data by accessing real data related to user, It is highly recommended to try other ways, since policies are meant to dictate access to models.

Edit 01 : Base on `I didn't register it. My policy and model name are the same (Trade and TradePolicy), and Laravel discover it automatically.`, Comment.

**GATE WITH POLICY WITHOUT MODEL**

So everything is right here, but the problem is you can't use it this way, you don't have model dedicated to this policy, so you can use `Gate` with policy.

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
      // Don't add it here while you don't have model
      // Auto discover work like this method, so they're both same.
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // Here you need to define a new gate related to policy.
        Gate::define('yourPolicy', [YourPolicy::class, 'yourPolicyMethod i guess']);
        Gate::define('yourPolicy', `App\Policies\YourPolicy::class`);
        Gate::define('yourPolicy', YourPolicy::class);
        // one of above ways base on laravel version.
        // or
    Gate::define('yourPolicy', function (User $user, Request $request){

    });
    }
}
```

As you can see after `// or` the way of defining gate is like policy, but, first way is your way.

And in controller :

```
public function store(StoreTradeRequest $request, StoreTradeService $service)
{

  if (! Gate::allows('yourPolicy', $request->all())) {
   ...
  }

}
```

Edit 02 :`Plain Old PHP Object (POPO)` with a little basic knowledge in `OOP`.

**Plain Old PHP Object (POPO)**

Alright, since you wanna stick to your method, I can only think of doing this in base idea of how to using models.

When i said policy meant to be to work with models, how about you don't have a common class?

Let's say, your policy don't need Trade, and it's only have purpose to handle request things, so this idea should be easy to do something like below :

```
class Request
{
   public array $request;

   public function __construct(array $request)
   {
      $this->request = $request;
   }
}
```

now let's create a new policy using `php artisan make:policy RequestPolicy`, and register it or test if it's auto discovered (in-case it didn't you can add it to `protected $policies` like below).

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        Request::class => RequestPolicy::class,
    ];
}
```

And then move your login to `RequestPolicy`:

```
class RequestPolicy
{
    public function store(User $user, Request $request): bool
    {
        return $user->id == $request['trader_id'];
    }
}
```

And of-course in Controller :

```
public function store(StoreTradeRequest $request, StoreTradeService $service)
{
    $this->authorize('store', new Request($request->(all)));

    // ...
}
```

NOW, in this way, which It's also a better way, you can recognize the purpose of policy, because it doesn't make sense if trade policy, got nothing to do with Trade model.

And in other-hand new policy make sense that it should handle things related to non-model things, the only problem is naming problem for your method, which in this case, instead of 'store' you can use something like 'storeTrade' or etc.

In this case, new policy will be flexible to other policies you're trying to achieve.

Of-course don't forget to check the `Request` namespace when you're trying to import it due to any conflict, which It should be like `App\Models\Request`.

Comment: I didn't register it. My policy and model name are the same (Trade and TradePolicy), and Laravel discover it automatically.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I think it might not be clear on the question, but my way works. I just didn't understand why I should have passed the Trade::class. I think you made that part clear with your answer by saying "pass or inject it someway or another." So my way should be one way of passing model. Instead of adding those registration codes, I'll stick with my code.

Comment: It seems like extra work just to avoid an array, which is no bothering me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I know how SO works. I think your answer has some good points and lots of unnecessary addition to the codebase which may helpful as an answer to a different question. Here is the think. Create another answer based on this: "When you're trying to use policy by not using a model, you should use/register it in another way, because as i said, it meant to be used with a model, which in this case you're not using it and application want you to pass or inject it someway or another." I'll accept it, because this answers my question.

Comment: @Bulent No need to accept it, Answer updated, following approach explained, and methods will be remain because they're necessary to know. Let's not keep discussing about this here, I'll delete rest of comments, because they're unnecessary. Good Luck.

Comment: THOSE WHO SEEK A SOLUTION TO THE SAME QUESTION: I accepted this answer because of the first paragraph. The rest of it might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional type hint for user in your policy class like this:

```php
public function store(?User $user, array $request): bool
{
    return true;
}
```

You can read about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#guest-users) ;)

Comment: I need the user in policy